# Existence of empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Empty set does not follow the definition of set, then why it is called a set,it does not contain well-defined collection of objects.

Comment: Why do you think it  "does not contain well-defined collection of objects"?

Comment: The collection of objects in the empty set is all those things that are not equal to themselves.

Comment: Do you consider a singleton set a "well-defined collection of objects"?